# Filter dataframe on sequence of rows conditional on two columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I have this type of data, where the numerical values in column `Sequ` define a sequence of rows and the character value in `Q` names the type of sequence:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Line = 1:12,
  Speaker = c(NA, "ID01.A", NA, "ID01.B", "ID07.A", NA, "ID33.B", 
              "ID33.A", "ID33.C", NA, "ID77.A", "ID77.C"),
  Utterance = c(NA, "Who did it?", "(1.99)", "Peter did.", "Hello!", NA, "So you're coming?", 
                "erm", "Yes, sure.", "(0.22)", "Good night?", "Yeah, sleep well"),
  Sequ = c(NA,1,1,1, NA,NA, 2,2,2, NA, 3,3),
  Q = c(NA, "q_wh", "", "", NA, NA, "q_decl", "", "", NA, "q_wh", "")
)
```

I want to subset the dataframe on those `Sequ` values that are numerical (rather than `NA`) AND where `Q == q_wh`. I can do this task by using `na_if` and then `fill`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Q = na_if(Q, "")) %>%
  fill(Q, .direction = "down") %>%
  filter(!is.na(Sequ) & Q == "q_wh")
  Line Speaker        Utterance Sequ    Q
1    2  ID01.A      Who did it?    1 q_wh
2    3    <NA>           (1.99)    1 q_wh
3    4  ID01.B       Peter did.    1 q_wh
4   11  ID77.A      Good night?    3 q_wh
5   12  ID77.C Yeah, sleep well    3 q_wh
```

But is there another, more direct way, without the detour to `na_if`and `fill`, to filter `df`?

**EDIT**:

I've found a solution that is without `fill` and `na_if`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Sequ) %>%
  mutate(Q = Q[!Q==""]) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Sequ) & Q == "q_wh")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ave` to replace by `"Sequ"` with first respective `Q`, finally `subset`.

```
df[!is.na(df$Sequ), ] |>
  transform(Q=ave(Q, Sequ, FUN=\(x) x[1])) |>
  subset(!is.na(Sequ) & Q == 'q_wh')
#    Line Speaker        Utterance Sequ    Q
# 2     2  ID01.A      Who did it?    1 q_wh
# 3     3    <NA>           (1.99)    1 q_wh
# 4     4  ID01.B       Peter did.    1 q_wh
# 11   11  ID77.A      Good night?    3 q_wh
# 12   12  ID77.C Yeah, sleep well    3 q_wh
```

**Note:** `R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)`.

Or using tidyverse dialect.

```
library(magrittr)
df[!is.na(df$Sequ), ] %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Q=ave(Q, Sequ, FUN=\(x) x[1])) %>%
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(Sequ) & Q == 'q_wh')
#   Line Speaker        Utterance Sequ    Q
# 1    2  ID01.A      Who did it?    1 q_wh
# 2    3    <NA>           (1.99)    1 q_wh
# 3    4  ID01.B       Peter did.    1 q_wh
# 4   11  ID77.A      Good night?    3 q_wh
# 5   12  ID77.C Yeah, sleep well    3 q_wh
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(Line = 1:12, Speaker = c(NA, "ID01.A", NA, "ID01.B", 
"ID07.A", NA, "ID33.B", "ID33.A", "ID33.C", NA, "ID77.A", "ID77.C"
), Utterance = c(NA, "Who did it?", "(1.99)", "Peter did.", "Hello!", 
NA, "So you're coming?", "erm", "Yes, sure.", "(0.22)", "Good night?", 
"Yeah, sleep well"), Sequ = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, NA, 
3, 3), Q = c(NA, "q_wh", "", "", NA, NA, "q_decl", "", "", NA, 
"q_wh", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: I have an older version of R. I guess `|>` is equivalent to `%>%`but what is equivalent to the backslash in `FUN=\`?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Yes, `|>` is the new base pipe, replace ```\```  by the word `function` and you got it. I recommend you or your admin to update R, though. Note, that I've updated with a tidyverse version.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've upvoted the solution. The problem however is that the `Q` column must not be populated with values such as `q_wh`; there needs to be exactly one such value at the head of the sequence. (This is  also the reason that my 'fill` solution is not the right one.)

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Could you help with an example where our solutions would fail then?

Comment: No, it's just that I need to post-process the data after the transformation and there it it is much more convenient not to have all the `Q` rows filled.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann This is not clear to me, in your expected output all `Q` are filled.